# Snakemake: Pull sample-specific information from config sheet

Tags: snakemake

In my workflow, I have a sample sheet that contains all the samples that are supposed to be analysed + the path where to find input files + the reference genome that is supposed to be used. All of this is sample-specific.

In my config file, I have a list of reference genomes and for each of them a list of paths of files depending on the tool.

In the rule that performs the alignment of each sample, I need to load some of those files but in a sample-specific way because the reference genome might not be the same for all samples.

Here is how I tried to solve this:

```
  params:  reference=lambda wildcards: table_samples['reference'][wildcards.sample],
           chrom_sizes=config[reference]['chrom_sizes']
```

However, when I try to run it like this, I get an error (directly when running Snakemake) saying that `reference` in the line of `chrom_sizes=...` is not defined.

Does anybody have an idea of a workaround?

EDIT: Some more information because I guess it's not really clear what I meant. Here is the relevant part of my config file.

```
hg19:
  bwa: 'path/to/hg19/bwa/reference'
  samtools: 'path/to/hg19/samtools/reference'
  chrom_sizes: '...'

mm9:
  bwa: 'path/to/mm9/bwa/reference'
  samtools: 'path/to/mm9/samtools/reference'
  chrom_sizes: '...'
```

And here is an example of the sample sheet.

```
name    path            reference
sample1 path/to/sample1 mm9
```

So, in the line `reference=lambda wildcards: table_samples['reference'][wildcards.sample]` I load the respective reference to be used for the current sample. Then, in `chrom_sizes=config[reference]['chrom_sizes']` I need to use `reference` as a variable to get `chrom_sizes` for the correct reference genome.

I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: So `reference` in `config[reference]['chrom_sizes']` is supposed to be a variable or string? It seems like it is supposed to be a string.

Comment: It is supposed to be a variable because it is sample-specific. I also added some more information to the original thread to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, taking the information from your comments I was able to make it work. I just had to modify them a little.

As I added to my original post, I actually needed `reference` to be a variable in order to pull the information for every sample individually.

As @JeeYem suggested, I tried to do the following:

`chrom_sizes = config[table_samples['reference']['{sample}']]['chrom_sizes']`

However, it seems not to be possible to use `{sample}` in this context. Instead, I changed it like this:

`chrom_sizes = lambda wildcards: config[table_samples['reference'][wildcards.sample]]['chrom_sizes']`

For now, it works! Thanks for everyone for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a ugly solution but should work.

```
params:
    reference = table_samples['reference']['{sample}']
    chrom_sizes = config[table_samples['reference']['{sample}']]['chrom_sizes']
```

You were defining a variable under `params` and attempted to pass its value within params itself; I'm not sure Snakemake can do that.

Comment: I think I tried that already and it didn't work but I will make sure to check again. Thanks! Btw, `'{sample}'` and `'{wildcards.sample}'` work in the same way I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put quotes around the `reference` key. Like you write it, Python interprets it as a variable.

```
chrom_sizes=config['reference']['chrom_sizes']
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really make it clear since the word `reference` is used too often. Actually, in the line you posted, `reference` is supposed to be a variable. This is critical because the reference is sample-specific and therefore might be different for every time the rule is executed.

Comment: I added some more information to the original post.